# SSH key login for some different user to a remote machine

Tags: unix, ssh, cron, key, ssh-keys

I have two remote machines, say machine A and B. I will denote myself as 'akash' and the other user as 'user'.

Currently I can ssh to A and inside A, I can SSH to B as `ssh user@B` which asks for the password of `user` for B.

I want to make a cronjob to scp certain number of files from A to B and I dont want to provide the login credentials of `user` in the script file which does that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just set up the key you want to use for the user you want to log in as on the remote machine. I don't understand the question.

Comment: How do I set up a key for `user`'s login credentials for B on A as the user `akash`?

Comment: You set up the keys allowed to log in as a given user by putting the key in that user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. It doesn't matter what user is *using* the key on the other machine.